# Луч должен игнорировать определённый слой. Unity 2D, C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы мой собственно созданный слой игнорировался определённым лучом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разумеется, просто нужно правильно составить `LayerMask`. Если мы посмотрим на определение метода `RayCast`:

`public static bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, float maxDistance = Mathf.Infinity, int layerMask = DefaultRaycastLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction queryTriggerInteraction = QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal);`

То увидим, что у него есть параметр `layerMask`, который и предназначен для фильтрации объектов по их слою.

---

Допустим, мы имеем условный слой Player под номером 8 и хотим сделать рейкаст, который проходит через все слои, кроме слоя Player.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
// получаем маску, которая затрагивает только слой Player
int layerMaskOnlyPlayer = 1 << 8;
// получаем маску, которая затрагивает все слои, кроме слоя Player
int layerMaskWithoutPlayer = ~layerMaskOnlyPlayer;
```

Рейкаст с такими масками выглядит так:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(origin, direction, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMaskWithoutPlayer))
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение